# ImageView stays empty if I extend Activity but works as expected if I extend AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, xml, android-imageview

I am not sure why I am not able to show images in my app using `ImageView`. Any ideas? Please ask if you need more information. Thanks!

In my `activity_main.xml` I have:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/armas_barcode" />
```

Perhaps the contents are irrelevant. In my `MainActivity` I have `public class MainActivity extends Activity {` then the image is not printed and no errors are logged. If I change it to `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {` then image is printed on screen as expected. The image is a vector image.

I have other vector images which I use in settings/preferences as `android:icon` and they seem to work fine.

My build.gradle is as folllows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.zebget.pricemap"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner" }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a layout file contains lines which do not work because they require e.g. a different API level, then they are simply ignored, the code compiles and the app works. More or less.

If your MainActivity extends `Activity`, then the following line in the layout will not be applicable.

> `app:srcCompat="@drawable/armas_barcode"`

This is because the `app` namespace ( xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto") only works with an `AppCompatActivity`.

But you can also set the drawable resource for your `ImageView` like this:

```
android:src="@drawable/armas_barcode"
```

Comment: you are right. It worked when I changed it to `src`. Do you know why Android Studio only shows `srcCompat` as default? and if this can be changed? It is not clear to me if using `AppCompat` brings any advantage whatsoever. It mosty seems to be creating AppInCompat ibities :)

Comment: @Evren Yurtesen - well, the Appcompat.xyz libraries are useful when you want to use a new feature in an app which should also run on older devices. And Android Studio shows you things as default because this way you notice their existence when otherwise you might have ignored it. This can be useful sometimes. But I admit I feel a bit bugged by the default layout files in my current Android Studio version (changing android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout to LinearLayout simply takes too long) Unfortunately I don't know how to get rid of the defaults - as a workaround I often copy older code